# Angular app will bootstrap based on the local storage value

Tags: angular6

Currently I'm working on angular 6, i want to check the local storage value before angular bootstrap module, If the value is present in local storage, i will call the bootstrap Module otherwise i want to block the bootstrap and the navigate to external login page url. How to do it using angular APP_INITIALIZER?

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

export function authGaurd(): () => Promise<any> {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(localStorage.getItem('app-token')) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        window.location.href = 'www.my-external-sso-login-page.com';// this sso page will set the local storge 'app-token', also i dont know how to re-direct to this page.
      }
    });
  };
}

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: authGaurd,
    multi: true
  }],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard, added my code here.

Comment: great, and what's the problem with your code?

Comment: As of now there is no pbm. Is it correct way or Is there an way to do this?

Comment: at first glance seems to be a correct way

Answer (score 0):

You can not stop to bootstrap the Angular app. But there is alternate way.
You can navigate once the application does load.